# when a request session is generated in weblogic how session id is determined

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, weblogic, session-cookies, jsessionid

When a session is invalidated in a web app, if i make to that app a new request with the invalidated jsessionid in cookie, what will be the new session's id? As i inspect,  a new session is generated but the session id remains same. I couldn't give a explanation to this. Is there such a convention to keep jsessionid in cookie and give that value to newly created session or am i doing something wrong? :)

The Scenario.

I have 2 webapps on same weblogic. The WLCookie name for these apps are same.

When user enters in appA i am making a asynchronous call to appB's logout servlet where the appB's session is invalidated.

when user clicks a link in appA which refers to appB, i am creating a new session in appB and when i check for the sessionid in cookie it still remains same which is first created in appA.

As i know, two webapps on same weblogic does not share their session's if not configured but although i invalidated appB's session from outside why newly created session has still the same session id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not confuse jsessionid with sessions. jsessionid is unique per container instance, where as session is per app. So, the session data won't propagate from AppA to AppB, just because the share the same jsessionid.

Comment: i am not passing it. it is stored in cookie and hence it passes.

Comment: Are you facing any issue because of this? I don't think you should.

Comment: i am not facing yet but i have to be sure about this issue. There are some integrations to other apps at this point and if a problem arises i have to be prepared.

Comment: How are you verifying that the cookie is being reused? also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429990/weblogic-jsessionid